# How can we run ASP.net 5 apps on full .NET Framework(4.5 >)

Tags: asp.net-core, coreclr

I want to try and run the MusicStore app located at `https://github.com/aspnet/musicstore` on the full .net Framework.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

1. Install DNX by following the instructions on the Home repo: https://github.com/aspnet/home
2. `dnvm upgrade -r clr`
3. `git clone https://github.com/aspnet/musicstore`
4. `cd MusicStore`
5. `git checkout release`
6. `cd src\MusicStore`
7. `dnu restore`
8. `dnx web`

In step 2 replace `clr` with `coreclr` to run on that framework.

Comment: did u mean dnvm upgrade -r clr , in step 2

Comment: Also when i do dnvm list , I see a list of beta versions , rc1 and rc2.             Each of the beta version has  coreclr , clr for x86 and x64 respectively.    So when i run on latest rc2 version for  Clr  , does it mean im running on .net4.6